# File permissions on data backups

Tags: permissions, backup, chmod

After making a `rm` related mistake on some of my files (which was fine because I have backups), I started thinking on how I could limit myself to making such mistakes. I have not done anything with file permissions, so I started reading up on that, but I think I might be missing something. I essentially would like to set my data backups (one: a Windows NT Filesystem external hard drive; two: a UNIX-based server, but I don't know the exact details of it) so that when I would try to remove or otherwise manipulate my files, I would either not be able to do so without `sudo` or some other override, or get some kind of "are you sure?"-prompt. Or, perhaps there is some kind of "standard" file permissions for data backups that people use that are better than what I'm thinking about?

I have been playing around a bit with `chmod` and various setups, but I can't seem to get it right. As far as I understand it `755` seem to be kind of standard, but as far as I understand that would not stop me from doing the kind of mistakes I did. What about `555`? Should you setup folders differently from your files? What do people generally use to protect their long-term storage, i.e. files that you won't access that often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the 'w' bit, you can't accidentally overwrite whatever you removed the 'w' bit from. If that's a directory, that means you can't add or remove files from that directory; if that's a file, that means you can't change the file. Downside of that method, however, is that you lose data (IMO, file permissions are part of your backup data).

An alternative is to use the 'immutable' extended attribute:

```
chattr +i file_or_directory
```

Downside of *that* method is that it can be confusing: `ls -l` tells you you can write to the file, yet if you try it the kernel says 'permission denied', even as root; you have to remember the extended attributes (which `lsattr` can tell you about)

On your final remark: the best way to avoid accidentally changing files which you don't need to access all that often is to, simply, *not make them available* for normal usage. Don't automatically mount the filesystem; make the `mount` step be part of your backup procedure. If you do that, all these issues go away.

Comment: Ah, interesting... Is there something equivalent of `chattr` and `lsattr` for OSX (which is what I'm sitting on)?

Comment: Dunno (I don't use OS X).

Answer (score 2):

It would generally avoid all the `sudo` and deliberately inhibiting yourself access to your files - it will likely cause you problems and possibly be so annoying you will just override your own protection mechanisms anyway.

I would instead use `trash-cli` which behaves like a desktop type trashcan where you can recover your file later if you make a mistake.
If you are using APT package manager you can install with

```
apt-get install trash-cli
```

Or use `yum` or `pacman` whatever your package manager is, then basically just replace the `rm` command with `trash` command. 
Then you can go crazy deleting your files and not have to worry about losing data because you can just recover your files later.
If you use verbose i.e. `trash -v <file>` trash-cli will list the directory where it is trashing files to.

Answer (score 0):

What about aliases? Typing alias at the command line you will see all defined aliases. I'd suggest adding something like:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

Define it in ~/.bashrc, (so you can remove it in future or change it to suit your needs.)

```
[mal@localhost ~]$ touch 123
[mal@localhost ~]$ rm 123
[mal@localhost ~]$ touch 123
[mal@localhost ~]$ rm -i 123
rm: remove regular empty file ‘123’? y
[mal@localhost ~]$
```

**OR**

Here is one more trick.

Create a file named `-i` in that directory using `touch -- -i` or `touch ./-i`

Now try `rm -rf *`:

```
[mal@localhost stack]$ touch {1..10}
[mal@localhost stack]$ touch -- -i
[mal@localhost stack]$ ls
1  10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  -i
[mal@localhost stack]$ rm -rf *
rm: remove regular empty file ‘1’? n
rm: remove regular empty file ‘10’? n
rm: remove regular empty file ‘2’? n
```

Here the `*` will expand `-i` to the command line, so your command ultimately becomes `rm -rf -i`. This command will prompt before removal.

**OR**

Use [safe-rm](https://launchpad.net/safe-rm)

> Safe-rm is a safety tool intended to prevent the accidental deletion
>   of important files by replacing /bin/rm with a wrapper, which checks
>   the given arguments against a configurable blacklist of files and
>   directories that should never be removed.
>
> ```
> Users who attempt to delete one of these protected files or directories will not be able to do so and will be shown a warning
> ```
>
> message instead:
>
> ```
> $ rm -rf /usr
> Skipping /usr
> ```

Comment: Use as you would use a bicycle with wheels when learning, do not get used to it. http://superuser.com/questions/384769/alias-rm-rm-i-considered-harmful

Comment: Best practice to avoid accidents is by training yourself and your habits, one day you could run into the system without guidance or friendly support and your habits will rule.

I've edited my post.

Comment: Okay, so reading your comments and the other thread linked to (as well as some links in there), it seems a lot of people just feel that you should just learn to do it the hard way, i.e. actually thinking about what you're doing whenever you're using `rm` or other dangerous commands. Does this also apply to backups, then?

Comment: It depends on many things. I'd prefer to do it in an automatically way. for example, make MySQL backup each weekend and do not keep more than 3 backups.

Comment: Well, my current backup is basically me manually putting my files (few, but large, several hundred GB per file usually) on the HD and the server. No external backup software, manager, or anything like that... Is that not something you should do?

Comment: I'm too lazy =) all my backup activities are performed with a bash/perl scripts.